# Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN card - no GUI wireless configuration available

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, intel-wireless

Machine is a Lenovo T400 with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Wireless card installed is an Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN mini-PCIe adapter. I can manage the wireless card manually via iwconfig, but the graphical network configuration control panel and associated menu bar icon don't see the card - it shows the card as unmanaged. In the menu bar icon, under Wireless Network, it says "device not managed".

iwconfig shows the card as managed. lshw provides this info (extra line breaks added for clarity):

```
*-network
  description: Wireless interface
  product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  logical name: wlan0
  version: 00
  serial: [redacted]
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: 
     pm 
     msi 
     pciexpress 
     bus_master 
     cap_list 
     ethernet 
     physical 
     wireless
  configuration: 
     broadcast=yes 
     driver=iwlwifi 
     driverversion=3.2.0-51-generic 
     firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 
     ip=10.1.0.92 
     latency=0 
     link=yes 
     multicast=yes 
     wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    ssid Marriott
```

(At the moment, I'm just on the unsecured wifi at a Marriott hotel.)

I've done a bit of searching and haven't seen anything on what might fix this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: cat /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 comes with Network Manager installed by default. It is designed to take over all the difficult work of network configuration. It assumes that if you have populated /etc/network/interfaces that you will do the hard work and it will *not* manage your connections. That is exactly what you see: "...In the menu bar icon, under Wireless Network, it says 'device not managed'."

If you wish NM to manage your network connections, remove all the wlan0 entries from /etc/network/interfaces leaving only:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Reboot and NM will take over management. Frankly, if it works for you, there is nothing really wrong the way it is now. It just appears a bit unusual because it's telling you that the wireless device is not managed by NM.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'm going to try that. Incidentally, my connection keeps completely crapping out. I have to reassociate (iwconfig essid Marriott) repeatedly throughout the day. Would NM help with this too?

Comment: It might help, although there might be other things we can try. It's easy enough to check, back up your current file and delete the entries in the original: sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak.

Comment: Removing the extra lines from /etc/network/interfaces did the trick on the wifi. Thank you!! As far as the other bit - on my Windows machine, I have to reauthenticate to the wifi (one of those "click here to agree to TOS before you can browse" pages), so maybe that's why the connection craps in Ubuntu, too.